# How to print without new line using pprint

Tags: python, printing, pprint

How to pprint.pformat string as like print. I am using pprint because I need to use indent

```
test = 'google\\nfirefox'
import pprint
pprint.pformat(test)

output is "'enable\\\\nshow'"
```

expected result is like

```
print (test)
google\nfirefox
```

Comment: Hint: if you want things to look like they are `print`ed: use print.

Comment: `pprint.pformat(var)-> str`
is to create string from var. 
To just print, you use `pprint.pprint(str)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
test = 'google\\nfirefox'
import pprint
string = pprint.pformat(test) # google\\nfirefox
print (eval(string)) # google\nfirefox
```

output:

```
google\nfirefox
```

> The `eval()` method parses the expression passed to this method and
>   runs python expression (code) within the program.

Comment: `eval(pprint.pformat(string)) == string` evaluates to `True` so this is doing nothing but wasting resources.

Comment: Would you mind comparing the output of `print (eval(string))` and `print(test)`?

Comment: also correct but also can you read an OP post, he  need to use indent

Comment: I did read the OPs question, i just wonder why you would answer him with something that's adding no indentation because it's the exact same output as printing the original string.

Comment: because he didnt specified indent, he just mentioned he would use it. He asked how to handle this problem he described in his post

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

If you want to print in lines splitet by '\n', you can try :

```
print(test, end ='\n')
```

If you want to print all text in the same line, you can try to replace '\n' by a space:

```
test. replace("\n", " ")
print(test)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a really weird thing but i hope this works for you

```
test = 'google\\nfirefox'
pprint.pformat(test).split("\\")[0] + "\\" + pprint.pformat(test).split("\\")[2]
```

just some really wierd string manipulation.

Comment: you could probably use ident with this